# How to do validation inside foreach

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

I have a form which has some text fields. Text fields may increase or decrease according to database table. If there are 3 warehouses in database it will show 3 text boxes with available quantity as place holder. Now user have to enter quantity no more than given in placeholder in each box. How can I do validation if user enter a value more than available (which will be shown as place holder) ?. Problem is validation should be according to foreach loop. My code is below,

```
<?php
if (!empty($ware_details)) {
                foreach ($ware_details as $data) {
                    ?>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo $data->warehouse_name; ?></label>
                        <input type="number" id="return_pro" class="form-control" base_url="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"  name="<?php echo $data->wh_warehouse_id;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $data->wh_product_qty; ?> Available">
                        <div class="dataDrop"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $data->wh_product_qty; ?>"/>
                    </div>
            <?php } }?>
```

Here as you see text boxes number is depending upon foreach loop. So how can I validate? Javascript or Ajax is ok.
I tried something like this,

```
<?php foreach ($ware_details as $data) {?>
<script>
function check()
{
    var stock = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
        var return_stock = document.getElementById('return_pro').value;
        if (parseFloat(stock) < parseFloat(return_stock))
        {
            alert("Return product can't be more than total stock");
            document.getElementById('return_pro').focus();
            return false;
        }
        //alert(return_stock);
        return false;
}
```

But I know it is fully wrong. Any idea?

Comment: If you don't output anything into the script (to make different functions), then you don't need multiple scripts.

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate? I can't see any `#quantity` element in the form. If you plan to have multiple ones, you cannot use an id but should use a class. You then could select the input elements and iterate them in javascript.

Comment: Please check. It was a mistake in question. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use html5 required attribute. This set of code may help you.

```
<input type="number" 
       min="1" 
       max="<?php echo $data->wh_product_qty; ?>" 
       name="<?php echo $data->wh_warehouse_id;?>" 
       required="required" 
       placeholder="<?php echo $data->wh_product_qty; ?> Available" />
```

Comment: Its a clean code. Simply adjust your doctype to support html5. Chrome, safari, ie and opera will support, mozilla is not supporting. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an id multiple times in the document, it needs to be unique. Either use classes to identify/group elements, or enumerate the ids:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    if (!empty($ware_details)) {
         foreach ($ware_details as $data) {
              ?>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo $data->warehouse_name; ?></label>
                        <input type="number" id="return_pro<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control" base_url="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"  name="<?php echo $data->wh_warehouse_id;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $data->wh_product_qty; ?> Available">
                        <div class="dataDrop"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quantity<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $data->wh_product_qty; ?>"/>
                    </div>
            <?php 
            $i++;
        } }?>
<script>
function check(i) {
    var stock = document.getElementById('quantity'+i).value;
        var return_stock = document.getElementById('return_pro'+i).value;
        if (parseFloat(stock) < parseFloat(return_stock))
        {
            alert("Return product can't be more than total stock");
            document.getElementById('return_pro'+i).focus();
            return false;
        }
        //alert(return_stock);
        return false;
}
// then in the validation trigger:
     for (var i=0; i< <?php echo $i; ?>; i++)
         check(i);
```

Comment: What you mean in last lines?

Comment: I mean where to give those lines?

Comment: Wherever you called `check()` before (in the form submit handler?), you now need to call it with every form's input number