# How to check input is more than place holder

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I have a input field like this

```
<input type="number" id="return_pro" name="available" placeholder="10 Available">
```

Here if user enter a value more than 10 (That is available), it should not accept and should show an error. How can I do that? I need to use this with the input tag itself. Because text fields comes inside an foreach loop. So number of text fields may increase.

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('return_pro').value > 10) {` ...

Comment: A comment by the poster refers to another question as their “real requirement”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="return_pro" name="available" placeholder="10 Available" onblur="check(this)">
```

Javascript:

```
 <script>

        function check(obj){
         var val=obj.placeholder.split(" ")[0];
         if(obj.value > parseInt(val)){
           alert('invalid');
           obj.value="";
           obj.focus();
          }
         }

    </script>
```

Comment: This is really works. But problem is I have more than one text fields. Which may increase and decrease according to database. I mean number of text boxes is depending upon database table. So we have to do this validation inside a foreach loop

Comment: why in foreach loop. We are passing 'this' in check function, which is current object. So no need to make loop. Am I getting you right or anything else you want?

Comment: No. Actually you need to look into this question. This is what my real requirement. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933097/how-to-do-validation-inside-foreach/22934192?noredirect=1#22934192

Comment: @SpamBox wait for 2 min, I am editing this.

Comment: 1 more problem dude. I need to focus to the text field if validation fails

Answer (score 0):

The **placeholder** is just what it says it is, a place holder and has no validation associated.

what you are looking for is some kind of validation, either by **javascript/jquery** or server side with **PHP**.

I suggest using a tutorial to learn how validation works like this one [here](http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/javascript-form-validation.cfm) as learning will be infinitely more valuable for the future, than simply copy and pasting some code that people provide on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" id="return_pro" name="available" placeholder="10 Available">
<input type="button" value="ok" id="submit"/>

$(function(){
    var placeholder=$("#return_pro").attr("placeholder");
   var available=parseInt(placeholder.replace(" available",""));


    $('#submit').click(function(){

     var val=$("#return_pro").val();
      if(val>available)
          alert("Sorry");
    });
});
```

I think This is actually you looking for.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5kCFv/2/)

Answer (score -1):

with jQuery

```
$("#return_pro").keypress(function(){
  var intValue = parseInt($(this).val()); 
  if(intValue > 10) {
  //value more more then 10, do something
 }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#return_pro').keyup(function(){
 var max = $(this).attr('placeholder').match(/[0-9]+/);
    if(parseInt($(this).val())>parseInt(max)){
        alert('Only '+max+' available');
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uQH64/